# Pick random user from message reaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How I can pick a random user from message reaction in discord?
I've read all the documentation, but I still do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Message.reactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) contains every reaction to the message, mapped by the id.
You just have to choose a random reaction and then choose one of the users that reacted:

```
if (message.reactions.size) {
  let reaction = message.reactions.random(1);
  let randomUser = reaction.users.random(1);
}
```

To choose the random reaction and the random user I used [`Collection.random()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=random).

If you don't want to choose a random reaction but you have your own, you can use this:

```
if (message.reactions.size) {
  let reaction = message.reactions.find(r => r.emoji.name == '');
  if (reaction) {
      let randomUser = reaction.users.random(1);
  }
}
```